# How can I re-order items in this array stored in Mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, algorithm, sorting

I have an array that's stored in MongoDB which I retrieve and display in order of how I retrieved it and let the user do stuff with it. The items could be exactly the same meaning nothing was changed, some could be deleted, or it could even be in a different order.

In the very end when it's submitted back to me, I have an array available to me which gives me a list of all the id's (id's that mongo create automatically). How can I re-arrange the array that's stored in MongoDB based on the array which I have retrieved which only has the id's.

If you want an example, It's stored in Mongo like this

```
components: [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5c323c8123f8cb1d1034c16a"
                },
                "componentName": "Apple"
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5c324a1a79e775435c91a919"
                },
                "componentName": "Banana"
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5c324a8707eca920fc1d31bc"
                },
                "componentName": "Orange"
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5c324ace07eca920fc1d31bd"
                },
                "componentName": "Watermelon"
            }]
```

And the array I get back looks like this

```
["5c324a8707eca920fc1d31bc", "5c324a1a79e775435c91a919"]
```

Meaning the first and last elements were deleted and the second and third were swapped. So I want the components array to be modified in mongo so it looks like this

```
components: [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5c324a8707eca920fc1d31bc"
                },
                "componentName": "Orange"
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5c324a1a79e775435c91a919"
                },
                "componentName": "Banana"
            }]
```

**PS. If you've never worked with MongoDB. The ID's in the MongoDB array can just be accessed simply using components[1].id which would give "5c323c8123f8cb1d1034c16a"**

I can't really think of a way to properly do this and the 'hacky' way I have in mind involves changing a bit of code I've already written so I'm wondering if there's a way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `.populate` method will help you:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population

```
Story.
  findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' }).
  populate('author').
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
    // prints "The author is Ian Fleming"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the ids from the user,
I would do the following:

1. Fetch the objects in array by IDs.
   Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/
2. Update the old array with the new array.
   Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 0):

There are no special operators for reordering (a complete list is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)), but you can try to optimize the number of operations. For example, if the user only removed a few indexes, an `$unset` will be faster than an overwrite. If a simple reorder happened, combining `$push` with `$pull` (although this will require two calls, as these two operators cannot access one array in one update).

In general, I'd suggest fetching the whole document and overwriting the whole value with `$set`; in every other case, you'll gain only a little with a lot of work.